Laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 is not powering the USB-C port so I can't use my monitors through the dock
My laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 is not powering the USB-C port, so I can't use my monitors through the dock.


Plug the laptop's charger into the dock. That way you theoretically charge the laptop.

In Settings app -> Power -> Power Mode put Ubuntu in Performance mode by clicking the Performance radio button. (It's the decisive one).


